# Node.js not writing to file?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a prime number sieve, and it works very well for me. However, it doesn't write the data to a file. It says that the primes were dumped to a file. Is there some size limit on fs.writeFile? The prime number array can get very large. Can someone help me with this?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var primes = ["2", "3"];
var num = 3;
var prime;
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Hundreds: 2");
console.log("Hundreds: 3");


while (true) {
  prime = true;
  var times = Math.pow(num, 0.5);
  for (var i=0;i<times;i++) {
    if (num % parseInt(primes[i], 32) == 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (prime) {
    var place = String(num).length;
    switch (true) {
      case place <= 3:
        console.log("Hundreds: "+num);
      break;
      case place <= 5 :
        console.log("Thousands: "+num);
      break;
      case 6 :
        console.log("Hundred thousands: "+num);
      break;
      case place <= 8 :
        console.log("Millions: "+num);
      break;
      case 9 :
        console.log("Hundred millions: "+num);
      break;
      case place >= 10 :
        console.log("Billions or above: "+num);
      break;
    }
    primes.push(num.toString(32));
    prime = false;
  }
  if ((num - 1) % 5000000 == 0) {
    fs.writeFile("Primes.txt", JSON.stringify(primes, null, '\t'), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Primes couldn't be dumped");
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("Primes dumped");
    });
  }
  num += 2;
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting `jsond` into a buffer?

Comment: Updated, removed inefficient jsond variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By running your code I came to the conclusion that somehow the primes calculation were disturbing the file write. So I tried using `fs.writeFileSync(...)` and it worked. The file is actually written pretty fast compared to the time it takes to reach your 5000000 threshold (in the long run, it may start taking a lot of time because you have over 300000 new primes being generated between your file writes and you write all the previous primes as well). I really don't know why the asynchronous method isn't writing it. It may be too busy calculating the primes. You know, nodejs asynchronous calls aren't parallel.

try something like this

```
...
if ((num - 1) % 5000000 == 0) {
    fs.writeFileSync("Primes.txt", JSON.stringify(primes, null, '\t'))
    console.log("Primes dumped");
}
...
```

the link to the api is here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Be aware that Primes.txt will be rewritten every time. Think about using `fs.appendFileSync(...)`. This would solve the problem taking too long to write the file after some time the code is running.

I've worked on '.appendFileSync()'. And for that, I had to imitate the 'JSON.stringify()' output for array type. This is my code so far:

```
var primes = ["2", "3"];
var num = 3;
var prime;
var fs = require("fs");

latestPrimes = "[\n\t2,\n\t3"

while (true) {
  prime = true;
  var times = Math.pow(num, 0.5);
  for (var i=0;i<times;i++) {
    if (num % parseInt(primes[i], 32) == 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (prime) {
    var place = String(num).length;
    if (place <= 3)
        console.log("Hundreds: "+num);
    else if (place <= 5)
        console.log("Thousands: "+num);
    else if (place === 6)
        console.log("Hundred thousands: "+num);
    else if (place <= 8)
        console.log("Millions: "+num);
    else if (place === 9)
        console.log("Hundred millions: "+num);
    else if (place >= 10)
        console.log("Billions or above: "+num);
    primes.push(num.toString(32));
    latestPrimes += ",\n\t"+num.toString(32)
  }
  if ((num - 1) % 5000000 == 0) {
    console.log('amount of primes:', primes.length)
    fs.appendFileSync("Primes.txt", latestPrimes)
    console.log("Primes dumped");
    latestPrimes = ""
  }
  num += 2;
}
```

when you stop the program, you just have add the string `"\n]"` to the end of the file to close the array.

Comment: I tried it, and the callback function seems not to have been called. I checked through and there was no message. I am also going to overwrite, because it is writing the entire primes list to the file. I don't want copies of the primes.

Comment: alright. I have executed your code and figured out somehow the primes calculation were disturbing the file write. Changing yo <code>fs.writeFileSync(...)</code> will solve your problem. I also could not write the file asynchronously. I have edited my answser.